# QScriptEngine::evaluate("print(test)") not functional anymore

Tags: qt, qt5, qtscript

I need to migrate qt/4.8.6 code to qt/5.9 . I am struggling with using print statement within QScriptEngine evaluate statement. In simplified form implementation looks like:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <QApplication>
#include <QtScript>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    QScriptEngine engine;
    std::cout << "Hello, world!\n";
    engine.evaluate("print('test\n\n')");
    }
```

.pro file

```
CONFIG += qt
CONFIG += console

SOURCES += main.cc

QT += widgets 
QT += script

sources.files =  main.cpp qscript.pro
INSTALLS +=  sources
```

->output to console:
Hello, world!

in qt/4.8.6 it prints out evaluated print statement to console "Hello, world! test", whereas in qt/5.9 it prints only "Hello, world!"

Any idea, why using print command is not working? Note, I need to implement printing to stdout by using js scripting+ evaluate.

Comment: Note, I would prefer to avoid migrating to QJSEngine because it would imply a huge migrating effort.

Comment: you could edit your post to include this information into your question.

Comment: According to the docs, it should work: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtscript-index.html#redefining-print

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce the problem. Could you share a complete [mcve] (including .pro).

Comment: output is just Hello World!

Comment: Please edit your question to include this (formatted) test code.